# how to create a table with nested rows using tree objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, html

I want to display table like below

```
Order  Name  Id 
1      aaa  1001
1.1    aab  1002
1.1.1  abb  1003
2      bbb  1004
2.1    bba  1005
```

The above order column is just depth of children items of same type.

The data shape would be

```
var data = [{
    id : "1001",
    name: "aaa", 
    children : [{
      id : "1002",
      name: "aab", 
      children : [
           {
             id : "1003",
             name: "abb", 
             children : []
           }  
      ]}

    ]},
    {
    id : "1004",
    name: "bbb", 
    children : [{
      id : "1005",
      name: "bba", 
      children : []
      }

    ]}
]
```

Here I want to use single table with rows repeated.

Please provide solution in angularjs or plain javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically I have tried one option like an nested ordered list of tables , but I want to do with one table . There is also one option of flattening tree objects to array of objects. But I am not able to get that order as mentioned in the above preferred output

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution using a recursive approach:

```
    var data = [{
    id : "1001",
    name: "aaa", 
    children : [{
      id : "1002",
      name: "aab", 
      children : [
           {
             id : "1003",
             name: "abb", 
             children : []
           }  
      ]}

    ]},
    {
    id : "1004",
    name: "bbb", 
    children : [{
      id : "1005",
      name: "bba", 
      children : []
      }

    ]}
]

tr = [];

function createTable(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        obj = {};
        for(var item in data[i]) {   
            if(  !Array.isArray( data[i][item] ) ) {
                obj[item] = data[i][item];
            }
            else {
                tr.push(obj);
                createTable(data[i][item])
            }
        }
    }    
}

createTable(data);

var table = '<table><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>';

for(var i=0; i<= tr.length; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for(var item in tr[i]) {
        table += '<td>' + tr[i][item] + '</td>';    
    }    
    table += '</tr>';
}

table += '</table>';
```

In this case, `table` would be: `<table><tr><td>1001</td><td>aaa</td></tr><tr><td>1002</td><td>aab</td></tr><tr><td>1003</td><td>abb</td></tr><tr><td>1004</td><td>bbb</td></tr><tr><td>1005</td><td>bba</td></tr><tr></tr></table>`

Putting it into an html file it shows a table like this:

```
  id    name
1001    aaa
1002    aab
1003    abb
1004    bbb
1005    bba
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to create an array with the required three "columns" (in fact: object properties). It is then a simple operation to output that as HTML table body content:

```js
function generateRows(data, order = '') {
    return data.reduce( (rows, data, i) => {
        let obj = {
            order: order + (order.length ? '.' : '') + (i+1),
            name: data.name,
            id: data.id
        };
        return rows.concat([obj], generateRows(data.children, obj.order));
    }, []);
}

// sample data
var data = [{
  id : "1001", name: "aaa", 
  children : [{
    id : "1002", name: "aab", 
    children : [{ id : "1003", name: "abb",
      children : [] }]
  }]
}, {
  id : "1004", name: "bbb", 
  children : [{ id : "1005", name: "bba",
     children : [] }]
}];

// convert
result = generateRows(data);

// Place table in document
document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = 
    result.reduce( (html, row) =>
        html + '<tr><td>' + row.order 
             + '</td><td>' + row.name
             + '</td><td>' + row.id + '</td></tr>',
        '');
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Order</th><th>Name</th><th>Id</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- generated content comes here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For info: the array created, before being output as a table, is:

```
[
  { "order": "1",     "name": "aaa", "id": "1001" },
  { "order": "1.1",   "name": "aab", "id": "1002" },
  { "order": "1.1.1", "name": "abb", "id": "1003" },
  { "order": "2",     "name": "bbb", "id": "1004" },
  { "order": "2.1",   "name": "bba", "id": "1005" }
]
```

To generate the table content from this is straightforward as can be seen in the code.

#### ES5 Version

Here is the same snippet for browsers that don't have some of the required ES6 features, like [function parameter defaults](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) or [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
function generateRows(data, order) {
  return data.reduce( function(rows, data, i) {
    var obj = {
      order: order + (order.length ? '.' : '') + (i+1),
      name: data.name,
      id: data.id
    };
    return rows.concat([obj], generateRows(data.children, obj.order));
  }, []);
}

// sample data
var data = [{
  id : "1001",
  name: "aaa", 
  children : [{
    id : "1002",
    name: "aab", 
    children : [{
        id : "1003",
        name: "abb", 
        children : []
      }]
  }]
}, {
  id : "1004",
  name: "bbb", 
  children : [{
    id : "1005",
    name: "bba", 
    children : []
  }]
}];

// convert
result = generateRows(data, '');

// optionally output object structure to console. Commented out here
// to leave room to see the table:
//console.log(result);

// Place table in document
document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = 
  result.reduce( function(html, row) {
    return html + '<tr><td>' + row.order 
                + '</td><td>' + row.name
                + '</td><td>' + row.id + '</td></tr>';
  }, '');
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Order</th><th>Name</th><th>Id</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- generated content comes here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `function generateRows(data, order = ''){}` that's an error.

Comment: @1252748: It is not if your browser [supports this ES6 standard feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) (FireFox, Chrome). If not, it is not that hard to use the old way of giving arguments a default value.

Comment: I thought it was probably something like that It gave me the error when I plugged it into jsbin though so I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The generic `tableMaker` function takes an array of objects and generates a table. Each object designates a row, where the array properties become the table headers (if the second parameter is set to true) and their values become the table cells. In this particular case in order to shape up the data to be sent to our `tableMaker` function we have a helper function called `getTableData`. I guess the following is what you needed...

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

function getTableData(data,init){
  return data.reduce((p,c,i,a) => {c.children = c.children.length > 0 ? getTableData(c.children,p) : "N/A";
                                   return tableMaker(a,true)},init);
}

var data = [{
    id : "1001",
    name: "aaa", 
    children : [{
      id : "1002",
      name: "aab", 
      children : [
           {
             id : "1003",
             name: "abb", 
             children : []
           }  
      ]}

    ]},
    {
    id : "1004",
    name: "bbb", 
    children : [{
      id : "1005",
      name: "bba", 
      children : []
      }
    ]}
];
myTable.innerHTML = getTableData(data,"");
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```